# Difference between binary division and its decimal division

Tags: divisibility, binary, decimal-expansion, binary-operations

Suppose I have one decimal number $23$ which decimal representations is $10111.$ Now $10111$ treated as dividend and divisor is $3$ which binary representations is $11.$ When $10111$ is divided by $11$ with Modulo-2 operation then remainder is zero. [See this image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hvoScV_KG0lSoNk6rfLyodiqUAt3WnL-/view?usp=drivesdk)

[image]

But $23$ divided by $3$ isn't  divisible and remainder isn't $0.$ My question is why is it possible to get remainder $0$ in case of binary and not $0$ in case of decimal?

N.B.--Modulo-2 and xor operation both are same thing.

Comment: What do you mean by "Modulo $2$ division"?

Comment: @lulu I mean division by Modulo 2  operation.

Comment: Ok, and what does that mean?  Be precise.  What exact computation are you proposing in this case?

Comment: @lulu I mean xor operation.

Comment: Still no idea what you are talking about.  XOR has nothing to do with division, right?  We get $10111,11\mapsto 10100$.  So what?

Comment: @lulu xor related with binary division see this http://www.ee.unb.ca/cgi-bin/tervo/calc.pl?num=1001110110&den=1101&f=d&e=1&m=1

Comment: @lulu see my updated question.

Comment: Long division, the remainder is 10 (i.e. 2 decimal) just like the 2 left over dividing 23 by 3.

Comment: @JTP the remainder is 10 but not 0, but in binary we get proper 0.

Comment: No we don't. I don't want to post an answer, but here's the image. https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qNoi.jpg

Comment: @JTP see my image in question, which shows binary division process  which is available in wiki, internet.

Comment: The remainder should be 10 in binary; the site you are using produces result using Galois field arithmetic, which is not the same as binary arithmetic

Comment: @Vasya Galois field arithmetic meaning?

Comment: @Vasya - thanks for that. I know binary. But no idea what Galois field arithmetic is. I'll look into it....

Comment: @Vasya why don't you answer of this question?

Comment: @Sagorika: Don't have time to write an expanded answer at the moment, check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field_arithmetic. Your web site mentions GF2.

Comment: the site you link to is doing polynomial arithmetic $\pmod 2$, as it says.  All it says is that $(x^3+x^2+1)\times (x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x) \equiv x^9 + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^2 + x \pmod 2$.  Nothing at all to do with $23$ or $11$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The remainder using binary long division will be $10_2$. This is not the same as using XOR operation.

$$
\begin{array}{c|r}
 & 0111\phantom{0}  \\
\hline
11 & 10111  \\
 & \underline{11}\phantom{00}  \\
 & 1011 \\
 & \underline{11}\phantom{0} \\
 & 101 \\
 & \underline{11} \\
 & \color{red}{10} \\
\end{array}
$$